# Awk only processes first line of input file? Extract attribute values from HTML elements

Tags: string, awk, string-parsing, command-line-interface, html-content-extraction

I have a huge text file filled with HTML attributes. I only want the value of the  tag.
Ex:

```
<option value="API" datatype="string" datatype_value="0">API</option>
<option value="Account" datatype="string" datatype_value="0">Account</option>
<option value="Address - asn" datatype="string" datatype_value="0">Address - asn</option>
```

I only want "API" after 'option value'.

Right now I have this:

```
awk -F "option value=" '{print $2}' /inputFilePath | awk '{print $1}'
```

I works but *ONLY* on the first line of the file. So my out put when I run the command above on the file only returns:

```
"API"
```

And not "Account", "Address" or anything after.

Any thoughts on anything I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify RS instead:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "<option value=\"" ; FS = "\""; } NF { print $1 }' file
```

Output:

```
API
Account
Address - asn
```

I just hope it works with your `awk` as `nawk` doesn't.

Yet another using GNU awk:

```
gawk '{ t = $0; while (match(t, /<option value="([^"]*)"(.*)/, a)) { print a[1]; t = a[2] } }' file
```

Explicitly I used `[^"]*` since I find empty values still valid for your query but you can change that to `[^"]+` if preferred.

Comment: Due to multiple characters in `RS`, the first `awk` needs `gnu` version.

Comment: +1; yes, multi-char. `RS` work in both `gawk` and `mawk` (but not in FreeBSD/OSX `awk`, for instance). Tangent re `nawk`: At least on Ubuntu, `nawk` isn't actually a separate `awk` implementation, but merely a _symlink_ to `awk` (which in in itself is by default a symlink to `mawk`). I'm curious what your platform is and whether your `nawk` is also just a symlink.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm a proud Gentoo user. I have both `mawk` and `nawk`. GNU awk is my main and `awk` is linked to it.

Comment: @konsolebox: Thanks. Given Ubuntu's behavior, we now know that `nawk` _means different things on different platforms_ (on stock Ubuntu, using your solution with _its_ `nawk` _would_ work, because it's actually `mawk`). I'm curious as to what `nawk` truly is on _your_ platform - the same as current FreeBSD `awk`, or a close relative? Does `nawk --version` report something meaningful?

Comment: @mklement0 It says `awk version 20121220`. Homepage is http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/awkbook/index.html. Mawk homepage is http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So what your system calls `nawk` is **BWK awk** (BWK = Brian W. Kernighan), the implementation used by "e.g. **FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD and OS X.**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK_programming_language#Versions_and_implementations). OS X, as usual, lags behind, however: the version on OS X 10.9.4 is `awk version 20070501`. I assume that all of these use BWK awk as the _default_ awk (I've verified it on FreeBSD and OS X). Does Gentoo have `gawk` as its default `awk`, or is that a symlink you created?

Comment: @mklement0 Gentoo by default uses GNU awk (gawk) and awk is always linked to it. It does not install `nawk` or `mawk` by default but the two are available through the portage and it allowed me to install them.

Comment: Helpful, thanks. To avoid ambiguity, I suggest avoiding the name "nawk" altogether and instead only referring to the name of the underlying implementation - in your case, "BWK awk", often called "BSD awk".

Answer (score 0):

The symptom suggests that **perhaps your `<option>` elements are on a *single* line rather than each element on its *own* line**.

<sup>**Update**: The OP to date hasn't provided feedback about what the original problem turned out to be, but given that the accepted answer works regardless of whether a single line contains multiple elements or just one, the above guess is likely.

(This answer originally contained a suboptimal `sed` solution that the first two comments reference - I've removed it.)</sup>

If you can use GNU `awk` or `mawk`, the **[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24878146/45375) is a great solution for the *specific* problem at hand**.

***Generally*, however, using a dedicated HTML/XML-parsing CLI is preferable** - it truly **understands the structure of the data and provides a more robust and flexible way to extract data**.

For instance, with the multi-platform web-scraping CLI [**xidel**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) the solution would simplify to:

```
xidel -q -e '//option/@value' file
```

- `//option/@value` is an XPath query that selects the `value` attribute of all `option` elements across all levels of the DOM (make more specific as needed).
- By default, xidel only extracts the contents of matching nodes, and prints each on a separate line.
- As an HTML parser, xidel parses the HTML correctly irrespective of variations in non-significant whitespace - it doesn't matter how many lines the elements of interest are spread across.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all `awk`

```
awk -F"<option value=" '{split($2,a,"\"");print a[2]}' file
API
Account
Address - asn
```

If you need the double quote:

```
awk -F"<option value=" '{split($2,a,"\"");print "\""a[2]"\""}' file
"API"
"Account"
"Address - asn"
```

Comment: If input was exactly the same as how it should i.e. formatted in multiple lines, something like `awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'` or `awk -F\" '/<option value=/ { print $2 }' file` would have be enough. But I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @konsolebox The solution I posted will work if there are more or less variable on the line and it may be on different position.

Comment: still only showing API and none of the other ones with this solution :(

Comment: @Jotne: A simpler version of your solution is `awk -F '<option value="|" ' '{print $2}' file`, but, as @konsolebox points out, this will only work with each line containing only _one_ `option` element - while the OP hasn't confirmed it, I suspect that may _not_ be the case and may indeed be the source of the problem. You could process fields in a loop, but with a multi-char. `RS`-capable `awk` the solution becomes much simpler, as @konsolebox's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score -1):

Add to your example code  $1 ~ /API/.
`awk -F "option value=" '{print $2}' /inputFilePath | awk '$1 ~ /API/ {print $1}'`

Comment: Still same results :( just outputting "API" and that's it

Comment: Try this method

`awk -F,  'match($1,/\<option value=\"([^\"]*)\"/, arr) {print arr[1]}' file`

Input:

API
Account
Address - asn

Comment: The OP wants to extract _all_ attribute values of interest, not just "API" - in fact, _only_ getting "API" is his/her _problem_ (the fact that the attribute-value extraction code in the question is flawed and doesn't handle values with embedded whitespace properly is a _secondary_ problem. This secondary problem has a simpler solution, as @konsolebox pointed out in a comment `awk -F\" '{ print $2 }' /inputFilePath` - but that only works with each `option` element on its own line, which seems to be the crux of the problem).